# I have regExp what it does?

Tags: javascript

```
/^\(?([1-9]{1,3})\)??([0-9]{9})$/
```

This is for veryfying numbers.
I am new to regular expressions. Can you explain to me what it does?

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5C(%3F(%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D)%5C)%3F%3F(%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D)%24%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/
 ^ <-- beginning of line
 \(? <-- optional "("
 ([1-9]{1,3}) <-- 1, 2, or 3 digits (each between 1 and 9) 
 \)?? <-- optional ")" (matches the first close parenthesis if multiple are present in the string)
 ([0-9]{9}) <-- 9 digits (each between 0 and 9)
 $ <-- end of line
/
```

It appears to match phone numbers which are prefixed by an area / country code

Comment: +1 thought that showing as image will give a clear idea, but I like this.

Answer (score 2):

To be be simple I am just uploading this picture (from http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5C(%3F(%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D)%5C)%3F%3F(%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D)%24%2F )

[image]

Comment: That picture itself isn't self-explanatory

Answer (score 2):

See this free spacing mode. I assume you're using PCRE

```
/^                #match the beginning of the string
 \(?              #match literal (, if exists
 (                #group 1
   [1-9]{1,3}     #match one, two, or three digit(s). The digit must be between 1-9
 )                #end of group1
 \)??             #match literal ), if exists
(                 #group 2
  [0-9]{9}        #match 9 digits, 0-9
)                 #end of group2
$/                #match the end of the string
```